# How can I see how many processor cores are working?

Tags: cpu, task-management

I have quad-core processor system. I was using Windows before installing Ubuntu. Windows by-default was using 1 core* and I could change that with `msconfig`. How can I do this in Ubuntu or is it necessary?

#### Windows was using one core for *booting*.

Comment: I feel it's important to note that Windows wasn't only using one core. The entry in MSConfig is talking about how many cores it should use in the booting process, and I'm fairly sure it's only useful to *limit* that number. I see no reason why it wouldn't use all of them by default.

Comment: Windows uses all cores by default. The startup option in msconfig is for limiting the number of processors. When limit is not enabled, textbox shows "1" which might look like the current running value, but it's not. It's merely the minimum you can type there.

Answer (score 64):

Type:

```
lscpu
```

in the terminal and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Now you have the info on cores used in your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Also - whatch out the line ex.: `Core(s) per socket:4`, it tells U the exact amount of Cores on the machine.

Answer (score 57):

You can see the usage of your CPU cores using top command.

1. Open a Terminal.
2. Type `top`. You will see some information about tasks, memory etc.
3. Type `1` to show individual CPU usage. You will see something like:

[image: top]

To start a new process which should execute only in one core, you can use taskset command.

```
taskset -c 0 executable
```

To monitor the existing process's CPU affinity, you can use this command:

```
taskset -cp $(pgrep -f executable)
```

note that the executable identity you will pass to this command can be './executable' if you started it that way.

Comment: This is a good answer, because it makes use of the top command which we always use anyway. I also never knew about taskset.

Comment: [jalal@ivcgpu1 divided]$ taskset -cp $(pgrep -f executable)
taskset: invalid PID argument: '-cp'

Answer (score 12):

As you have not specified your Desktop environment I will assume you are using Using Ubuntu

For a graphical way to check your cpu usage, search your system for an application called System monitor.

The Resources tab will show activity of each core

[image]

Whilst the Processes tab will show cpu usage for individual programmes.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

`htop` tool provides [graphs for cpu core(s) usage](https://serverfault.com/a/180724)

install htop via terminal:

```
apt-get install htop
```

run htop via terminal:

```
htop
```

[image: htop in the ubuntu terminal looks like this]

Comment: I recommend expanding this to explain how to use it for that purpose and to show what it looks like (when used this way).

Comment: You have not even mentioned how to install it, as it doesn't come with the system.

Comment: Nice complement to `top`!

Answer (score 4):

Sensors does this too, but it also tells you the temperature the cores are running at, very cool.

Type `sensors` in the terminal and it will tell you if you already have it installed, once it's installed you just write `sensors` [image: here be sensors]