# Monitor number of running processor cores via terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, top

I have a server where there are 144 procs and is being used by multiple people with the same account id. Is there any way I can see how many processors are free (in the terminal) so that I can schedule my program to run with the appropriate number of procs? `top` does give me the list, but I cannot scroll down and see when (something like) > 31 procs are busy. The server is behind a firewall, so installing `htop` is also not an option. I saw this [How can I see how many processor cores are working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257248/how-can-i-see-how-many-processor-cores-are-working) but it didn't help much. The `taskset` command mentioned here is giving me a `bad usage` error. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to see how many processes are currently running according to the linux scheduler using:

```
grep procs_running /proc/stat
```

You may want to also take into consideration that some processes are temporarily blocked (say on I/O or waiting), so it may be also worth taking these into consideration:

```
grep procs_blocked /proc/stat
```

Comment: Is there any way I can pipe the name of the processes/programs which are running on these 'procs_running' into the terminal/file?

Comment: Try: ps -eo stat,command | egrep "^D|^R" | cut -b6-

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. :)

Comment: and @Colin Ian King, if it is not a bother, can you explain that command a bit?

Comment: ps: -e selects all the processes, -o stat,command prints out the process running status and command being run.  The egrep filters out the processes in the D (uninterruptible sleep) and R (running) states. The cut -b6- strips off the leading 6 chars (the process state) of the output leaving you with just the process names of processes in the D and R states.